# ArcGIS JavaScript API: How to show company specific portal login screen when trying to access secure layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have written a webapp with the ArcGIS JavaScript API and all is working fine. Now I am trying to add secured layers to the web app and the app starts asking for credentials via a default login screen. I could use that, just entering username and password, but most users don't know their user name and password for ArcGIS.
[image]
The company has implemented SSO with ArcGIS so users don't have to fill in their credentials. Users typically go to the main company.maps.arcgis.com site and get to a company specific login screen where they have the option to click this SSO button.
[image]

My question; how can I make the JavaScript API show this company specific login page with SSO button instead of the default one?

I tried registering `oauthInfo` and `serverInfo` setting but without success.

Did anybody else ever built this?

Answer (score 1):

The SSO sign in prompt should occur as long as you're using [OAuthInfo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-OAuthInfo.html) and registering it with the [IdentityManager](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-IdentityManager.html). You'll have to make sure that you:

- [Add and register an application](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/add-app-url.htm) in the organization where
  the data is coming from. The redirect URI should point to the server
  that's hosting the application URL.
- Get the Client ID from the registered application and add it to the [appId](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-OAuthInfo.html#appId) in OAuthInfo along with the [portalUrl](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-OAuthInfo.html#portalUrl) property (which should be https://company.maps.arcgis.com)
- Set the popup property to false.
- Verify all the data is coming from the same organization. If it's not, then you may get another prompt since it's not registered with the IdentityManager.

Here's an example of what the OAuthInfo should look like:

```
const info = new OAuthInfo({
    // Swap this ID out with registered application ID
    appId: "APPID",
    portalUrl: "https://company.maps.arcgis.com/",
    flowType: "auto", // default that uses two-step flow
    popup: false,
});

esriId.registerOAuthInfos([info]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Before I try this, one question; why is popup: "false" needed?

Comment: There are two workflows with OAuth - one is where the sign in shows up on the same webpage and the other is the sign shows up in a new popup window. The sample above shows the sign in coming up on the same page so the popup property is set to false. If you want a separate popup, set that to true and you need to have a popupCallbackUrl set https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-OAuthInfo.html#popupCallbackUrl